# Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free,How to fix this error in xampp?

Tags: php, web, xampp, webdev.webserver

guys I'm a newbie trying to learn php. Just downloaded Xampp but can't find the fix for errors. I downloaded apache 2.4 in the past, but after this problem occurred I stopped Apache services and deleted the folder. It's still having the same problems. Please let me know the fix if you know.

[image: the error]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous apache service is still running and use the port, other apache instances can't run on the same port.

You can use task manager to stop your apache service.

Comment: man i tried but as soon as i start apache in xampp it comes back on again

Comment: Try changing apache port in XAMPP > Config > Service and Port Settings

Comment: solved it! my brother downloaded apache 2.4 before, that was the thing causing problem